# ¿Cómo saber el tamaño de la terminal en Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Estoy haciendo un programa que muestra texto por pantalla, entonces necesito que no se descuadre según el tamaño de ventana que utilice el usuario. Se que hay un comando para calcular el tamaño del ancho de la terminal, ¿alguien sabe cuál es?

Comment: Postiga, por favor muestranos el código del programa que desarrollas o un poco más del contexto del problema.

Comment: has probado con: `$LINES` para las filas y `$COLUMNS` para las columnas, Hay una pregunta en: [StackOverflow Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263890/how-do-i-find-the-width-height-of-a-terminal-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resumiendo algunos ejemplos de [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263890/how-do-i-find-the-width-height-of-a-terminal-window) que te comentaron, tienes varias opciones:

- **En `bash`, tienes las variables `$LINES` y `$COLUMNS`**

  ```
  echo "Lineas: $LINES Columnas: $COLUMNS"
  ```

  Lamentablemente esto tiene un problema, al ser variables de shell y no de entorno no se exportan al proceso hijo, por lo que no podrías usarlas en un script. En realidad se podría forzar la exportación de estas variables agregando `trap 'export LINES COLUMNS' DEBUG`, por ej. al `.bashrc`, es un truco poco elegante y no lo recomiendo habiendo mejores opciones.
- **Comando [`tput`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput)**

  ```
  echo "Lineas: $(tput lines) Columnas: $(tput cols)"
  ```

  Acá el tema es que tenemos que tener instalado el paquete `ncurses`, por lo general es lo que ocurre, salvo en algunos entornos emulados en Windows que no lo traen por defecto. (Por ej `mingw`)
- **Comando [`stty`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty)**

  ```
  echo "Lineas: $(stty size | cut '-d ' -f1) Columnas: $(stty size | cut '-d ' -f2)"
  ```

  En este caso dependes de la instalación de las [GNU core utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)